# Router cannot match correct route with parameter

Tags: dart, angular-dart

My application is using HashLocationStrategy. I found that angular router cannot match correct route if both routes have a parameter.

My problem is in my Dart code. The router only recognize /edit/:id but cannot handle request to /article/:id.

http://localhost/#/edit?id=xxxxxx (work)

http://localhost/#/article?id=xxxxxx (not work)

app_component.dart

```
@Component(
    selector: 'body[app]',
    templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
    directives: const [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
)
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true),
  const Route(path: '/edit/:id', name: 'Edit', component: EditComponent),
  const Route(path: '/edit', name: 'Edit', component: EditComponent),
  const Route(path: '/article/:id', name: 'Article', component: ArticleComponent),
  const Route(path: '/...', name: 'Auth', component: AuthComponent)
])
class AppComponent {

}
```

app_component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Update: The problem is fixed in both route.navigate and provide URL to browser directly.

```
@Component(
    selector: 'body[app]',
    templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
    directives: const [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
)
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true),
  const Route(path: '/edit/:id', name: 'Edit', component: EditComponent),
  const Route(path: '/edit', name: 'Edit', component: EditComponent),
  const Route(path: '/...', name: 'Auth', component: AuthComponent),
  const Route(path: '/article/:id', name: 'Article', component: ArticleComponent),
])
class AppComponent {
    final Location _location;
    final Router _router;
    AppComponent(this._location, this._router);

    @override
    ngOnInit() {
       this._router.navigateByUrl(this._location.path());
    }
}
```

Comment: what error do you have?

Comment: I have got no error, but ArticleComponent is not shown.

Comment: Try moving `/article/:id` route before `/...` route. I don't know what `/...` child routes look like, but there is some ambiguity, order of routes matters.

Comment: What did fix it? You moved the route up as I suggested in the first code block, but from your edit it looks like the 2nd code block should show the fix.

Comment: The problem seems resolved after I trigger the route manually base on location.path(), but I do not ensure whether this is the correct way.